# RETS Feed Fething with PHRETS giving ErrorCode 20401

Tags: php, phrets

I am using PHRETS Library to fetch the rets feed. At the time of image fetching its providing me the ErrorCode "20401". Object to fetch image from rets api as:

```
$objects = $rets->GetObject('Property', 'CmmlRntl', '75290', '*', 0);

foreach ($objects as $photo) {
 $photo = $photo->getContent();


 if($photo){
 echo "<hr><pre>";

 var_dump($photo);
 //echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode('') . "\" />"; 
 echo "</pre><hr>";
 }
}
```

Output Getting As:

```
string '<RETS ReplyCode="20401" ReplyText="Requested Type not found." />' (length=64)
```

How i can get rid from this Error.?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and couldn't find an answer to that problem, even after asking the MLS IT dept.

What I ended up doing was to have a cron that re-tries to fetch those images which I flag as 'failed', but the retry will is limited to 2 retries. If, after that, the image is still failing, then the retry script won't try to fetch it again.

For the most part, the error happened due to a failure on the MLS server, and usually I was able to fetch the image on the 2nd try.